# Use of INotifyDataErrorInfo in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inotifydataerrorinfo

I know that ASP.NET MVC has good validation using Data Annotations. Is it possible to use INotifyDataErrorInfo for data validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you could use the [`IValidatableObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.aspx) interface. Scott Gu [`blogged`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/10/class-level-model-validation-with-ef-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) about it.